# Blackberry http connection reading contents of a webpage. Some punctuation marks are incorrectly read

Tags: http, blackberry, get

I have a piece of code that opens a HTTP connection to read the data contained on a webpage.

```
        HttpConnection h = new HttpConnection();
        InputStream input = h.openInputStream();
        int len = (int) h.httpConn.getLength();

        StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

        if(len > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[len];
            while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) 
            {
                raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
            }
        }

        response = raw.toString();
        input.close();
        h.httpConn.close();
        //System.out.println("Response -----> " + response);

        return response;
```

This code works absolutely fine, but on certain punctuation marks its not reading properly.  For example >> ' << an apostrophe comes out as >> â <<.

I'm guessing it might be something to do with encoding but I have tried UTF-8, UTF-16 and ASCII and this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this work for me when I was getting odd characters in place of punctuation:

```
public String getContents(InputStream stream) {
    String contents = null;
    try{
        contents = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(stream), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //encoding error
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
```

you can use

```
raw.append(new String(data, 0, len, "UTF-8"));
```

passing in the name of a character enconding, in this case UTF-8.